# SSRS - Report Action

Tags: ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have a report that contains a LookUpSet expression to pull the total # of Self-Service, total # of subscription and total # of executions from 2 different dataset. `=Join(LookupSet(Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Fields!ReportUNC.Value, Format(Fields!cntSelfService.Value, "###,#######0"), "ExecutionCount"))`

[image]

What I am trying to set-up is that when the number is clicked (138, 121, 259) another report will load pulling the number that was clicked? so, if I clicked the 138 it will only load the sales report data for that 138, but I'm stuck and I can't figure out how to configure it. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it sounds like you're asking for is a "Drillthrough Action".
[MS - Drillthough](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/add-a-drillthrough-action-on-a-report-report-builder-and-ssrs?view=sql-server-2017)

```
Rt-Click on the textbox containing the "138" and select "Textbox Properties".
Click "Action" on the left.
Select the "Go to report" option on the right.
Click on the "Browse" button and browse to the report you want to run.
Click on the "Add" button to add the parameter you want to send to the report.  When you do so, the "Name" column will contain a list of the parameters the report has in it.  Select the appropriate one that you want to pass the "138" into.  The under the "Value" column, select the field containing the "138".
Click "OK".
```

So what you're doing is creating an action that when you click the field runs a selected report and passes in the parameter(s) needed to run the report.

I'd suggest formatting the text in the field to have a hyperlink appearance (underlined blue text), so the user knows that it's a clickable field.